# Maven - Skip building test classes

Tags: maven-2

Is there a simple way to not build the test classes?

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: skip compiling or skip executing?

Comment: I need to run jetty without compiling the test classes.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip) on the Maven Surefire Plugin, `-Dmaven.test.skip` *should* skip both compilation and execution of the tests. By contrast, `-DskipTests` just skips the test *execution*: the tests are still compiled.

Comment: +1 I hate the naming, however. It's completely non-obvious to me why `skipTests` just skips *executing* the tests and `maven.text.skip` skips *compiling and executing* the tests. I always have to look up which one is which.

Answer (score 21):

Just to be explicitly clear:

`skipTests` **will compile** anything in the `<testSourceDirectory>`, but **will not execute** them.

`maven.test.skip` will **NOT compile** any tests, but **WILL execute** any compiled tests that made their way into the `<testOutputDirectory>`.

So the behavior of the above 2 is opposite. Just wanted to point out that `maven.test.skip` doesn't skip compilation AND execution if test files are unpacked/copied/etc. into `<testOutputDirectory>`.

Also, depending on which version of Maven your using, there's also `maven.test.skip.exec=true` which **additionally skips test execution** similar to skipTests.

Comment: That is unfortunately not true, at least in maven 3.0.5 and maven-compiler-plugin 3.5.1. You can test it in every project containing tests: `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true && mvn test -Dmaven.test.skip=true` will compile the tests (because of the first package-execution) but not run them in the second command. Assuming standard directories, `target/test-classes` will contain all tests afterwards, but they have not been executed.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted as such

Answer (score 10):

Run a [phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) that doesn't include `test-compile`, for example `compile`.

```
mvn clean compile
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an expert at maven, but what I use in my current project is:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Depending on your use case using:

```
mvn compile -DskipTests=true
```

might work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249345/disable-phases-in-maven-lifecycle), which actually overrides a plugin execution by adding the following snippet in your pom.xml by default:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-testCompile</id>
          <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This seems to work but definitely does not disable phase but disables the default actions that a plugin defines at a specific phase.