# How to permanently exclude one test class in a Maven build

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to exclude a single test from my maven build (I don't want the test to be compiled or executed). The following doesn't work:

```
<project ...>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/MyTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

What is the correct way to achieve my goal? I know that I can use the command-line option `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, but I would like this to be part of the `pom.xml`.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123075/maven-how-can-i-skip-test-in-some-projects-via-command-line-options), is similar to your needs. (not the question, see the first answer)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Skip the test

From the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), if you want to skip a test, you can use:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/MyTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

See the diference, in your example, you use `<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>`, and the docs say that you shoul use `<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>` plugin instead.

And, if you want to disable all test, you can use:

```
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
```

Also, if you are using `JUnit`, you can use [@Ignore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html), and add a message.

### Exclude the test from compilation

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656223/1126380) answer, you can use. The trick is intercept the `<id>default-testCompile</id>
<phase>test-compile</phase>` (default test compile phase) and exclude the class:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-testCompile</id>
      <phase>test-compile</phase>
      <configuration>
        <testExcludes>
          <exclude>**/MyTest.java</exclude>
        </testExcludes>
      </configuration> 
      <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>                  
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Exclude one test class, by using the exclamation mark (!)

```
mvn test -Dtest=!LegacyTest
```

#### Exclude one test method

```
mvn verify -Dtest=!LegacyTest#testFoo
```

#### Exclude two test methods

```
mvn verify -Dtest=!LegacyTest#testFoo+testBar
```

#### Exclude a package with a wildcard (*)

```
mvn test -Dtest=!com.mycompany.app.Legacy*
```

This is from: https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/10/run-one-or-exclude-one-test-with-maven/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of skipping the compilation and execution of test by default in Maven is to add the following property in your `pom.xml`:

```
 <properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
 </properties>
```

You still can change the behavior by override the property from the command-line:

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=false
```

Or by activating a profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>testing-enabled</id>
        <properties>
           <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable only a single test and not all of them?