# Maven skip specific test

Tags: maven, unit-testing

Is there any way of getting maven to skip a specific test class?

I am developing my tests now, and each time I write a new test or debug a current test,  I do a "mvn test"  which of course runs through them all.

Lets say I have a package structure like:

```
com.me.a
com.me.b
```

and I am developing in b -- How do I skip all the tests in a? Can this even be done?

Comment: Seems like it may be a repeat, but try the solution given here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273160/how-to-permanently-exclude-one-test-class-in-a-maven-build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273160/how-to-permanently-exclude-one-test-class-in-a-maven-build)

Comment: If you do it within your IDE you don't need to run `mvn test`.