# how to avoid runing testcases without using skipTests in maven while using the mvn clean install

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have written the test cases but it is activating when I am running the mvn clean install test cases also running but my case no need to run the test cases while running the mvn clean install when I am using the particular profile then only activate the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure surefire plugin in your pom.xml to include/exclude tests based on their names, and use different configuration for the profiles you want to run these tests on.
Something like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>without-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/someTests.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>without-other-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/otherTests.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

See more about it [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Answer (score 0):

Name the tests you dont want to run with a suffix that enables you to group them ...

e.g. sometimes we use `...FunctionalTest` to label functional tests. These tests can then be grouped/included/excluded when running unit tests, as a part of the standard build.

See this post for more info [How to permanently exclude one test class in a Maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273160/how-to-permanently-exclude-one-test-class-in-a-maven-build)